# Regular expression for swapping first and last names for any number of names in a string

Tags: regex, text, replace

Basically I am hoping for a regular expression (or a series of regular expressions) that is able to sort text containing a list of names in the following way:

`"Hill, Tommy" -> "Tommy Hill"`

`"Miller, James | Boye, Henry" -> "James Miller | Henry Boye"`

I just can't seem to figure out an expression that is able to swap the first and last names for a series of names separated by `" | "`, regardless of how many `" | "` there are, or if there are none at all.

Any help really would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can create a regex pattern to match endless number of `lastname, firstname` combinations, in the substitution pattern you cannot create a "loop" in the way you're looking for.

It can be helpful to think that regex only gives you one match, and you can use the numbered parts of that match in the substitution pattern. But you can not run the same substitution pattern repeatedly against the parts of the match.

To achieve such a loop, you'll have to use your languages loop constructs.

Comment: Ah ok, that does make a lot of sense actually. Thank you! I should be able to use a loop I was just really hopeful it could somehow magically be done with just one RegEx.

Comment: Happy to help. In case you found my answer helpful, you can click the up arrow to upvote it, or click the checkmark to mark this as the accepted answer. 